# Form input returns "1" instead of real value

Tags: forms

On this page I have an select list with values from a file directory. This works. Only after submitting it doesn't get the value of it. It makes it "1". Normally with a "normal" select list this should work I guess.

Problem: $form_state['input']['edit']['ios_cert'] doesn't return selected value.

Code (in hook_form):

```
$files = array();
foreach(glob("C:/wamp/www/drupal2/sites/default/files/*.pem") as $filename) {
   array_push($files, substr(strrchr($filename, '/'), 1));
 }

$form['replace_textfield']['edit']['ios_cert'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Select right certificate file'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => $files,
    '#default_value' => $ios_key,
    '#weight' => 45,
  );
```

Code (hook_submit):

```
$ios = $form_state['input']['edit']['ios_cert'];

$query = db_update('push_notifications_api')
->fields(array(
'app_id' => $app_id,
'GCM' => $gcm,
'ios' => $ios,
'ios_mode' => $ios_mode,
))
->condition('app_id', $oldid)
->execute();
drupal_set_message(t('@title has been updated succesfully.', array('@title' => $title))); 
dsm($form_state);
```

Result:

[image: dsm result]

And it should be something like "Filename-djfklasjklf.pem"

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you're setting the '#options' property of the form element as an indexed array such as:

```
$form['replace_textfield']['edit']['ios_cert']['#options'] = array(
  0 => 'filename1.pem',
  1 => 'filename2.pem',
  [...]
);
```

This means that the first option in the select tag will have a textual label of "filename1.pem" and a value of 0, so 0 will be sent via GET/POST to the receiving script.

In order to send the filename you need to also have the filename as the key of each option in the '#options' array (i.e it should be a self-keyed associative array).

A simple way to achieve that would be to change the line:

```
'#options' => $files,
```

to:

```
'#options' => array_combine($files, $files);
```

or, change:

```
array_push($files, substr(strrchr($filename, '/'), 1));
```

to:

```
$filename = substr(strrchr($filename, '/'), 1);
$files[filename] = filename;
```

Answer (score 2):

I already got it.

I added this:

```
foreach ($files as $record){
    $options1[$record] = $record;
 }
```

And then use $options1 as '#options'

Comment: Yup, `#options` is an associative array of `key:label`. The array value is only used in the user-facing text, and might be a translated string, while the array key is what actually gets submitted.